# Memory footprint of a parsed XML file in Classic ASP?

Tags: xml, asp-classic, iis-6, benchmarking

Anyone know of a way to find out the amount of memory/size of a XMLDocument once it has parsed a XML file? I've been doing "beer mat" calculations so far but have been asked to come up with some more legit numbers through monitoring some how.

I need to create about 1500 XML files (via FreeThreadedXMl-DOM object), which verge between 3-9K in size and store them in Application vars but our SysAdmin is worried about us gobbling up too much memory.

Other than the crude method of booting up a fresh IIS instance and then loading everything in and monitoring before and after memory usage in Task Manager I can't think of a way of doing it with a bit more accuracy.

Update:

Tried the crude method and it works really well. Loaded up 300 parsed xml docs into the application space and it gobbled them up really well. Multiplying that up to the 1500 odd files and it will barely push 60Mb of Memory for data storage. Perfect :)

Comment: Why would you want to load every xml file in an application var?

Comment: To save us having to keep sucking it in from disc and parsing it. Each XML file contains product details. We might render various info from 20+ of these products on a page, thats alot of parsing we can cut down on by caching them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to more accurately monitor memory usage by setting up a test case in Windows Scripting (VBScript/JScript). It's the same language environment classic ASP uses, minus all things that make up IIS/ASP and use memory of their own.

Load a representative amount of XML documents into an array, and display a message box before and after. This way you can assess through a task monitoring tool how much memory they actually take up. After that you can compare it to how ASP behaves to get an idea of the overhead (if any) the server generates.

Answer (score 0):

Your crude method sounds like the most accurate and meaningful measure, I confess. Especially from your sysadmin's perspective.